# R glmnet multiresponse gaussian, print 'double' error, data import from SPSS

Tags: r, import, spss, gaussian, glmnet

Ι am an absolute beginner at R. I want to use it to do a lasso multiresponse regression model, using a large number of MRI brain metrics to predict 3 or 4 behavioural outcome variables. The original datasets are in SPSS. I have used to 'foreign' package to import them from SPSS. One SPSS file consists solely of all the predictor variables, and the other one consists solely of 3 dependent variables. I have 26 participants. Here is the code:

```
> x=read.spss("F:\\Google Drive\\Master\\Thesis\\Predictors.sav", use.value.labels=FALSE, to.data.frame=TRUE,
+ max.value.labels=FALSE, trim.factor.names=TRUE,
+ trim_values=TRUE, reencode=NA, use.missings=to.data.frame,
+ sub=".", add.undeclared.levels="sort",
+ duplicated.value.labels="append",
+ duplicated.value.labels.infix="_duplicated_")

> y=read.spss("F:\\Google Drive\\Master\\Thesis\\Response.sav", use.value.labels=FALSE, to.data.frame=TRUE,
+ max.value.labels=FALSE, trim.factor.names=TRUE,
+ trim_values=TRUE, reencode=NA, use.missings=to.data.frame,
+ sub=".", add.undeclared.levels="sort",
+ duplicated.value.labels="append",
+ duplicated.value.labels.infix="_duplicated_")

> fit=glmnet(x, y, family="mgaussian", alpha=1.0, weights=rep(1,26), offset=NULL, nlambda=100)
Error in mrelnet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Any idea how to solve that error message? Again,  I have to stress I am an *absolute* beginner in R.

Comment: Please make your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: might [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457624/r-glmnet-list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-double) be of help?