# glmnet error "Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs, : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Tags: r, regression, glmnet

[My data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PUPWoS_7XsmplDG_mFjjOis-IopPnRVM/view?usp=sharing)

I am having a problem running logistic regression for my data, first I used glm function in r but got the following warning:

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

Now I am trying to do glmnet because the data is very sparse:

```
x = data[, 2:27]
y = data[, 1]
y = as.matrix(y)

fit = glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial")
```

But I get the following error which I do not understand:

```
Error in lognet(x, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R glmnet : "(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457624/r-glmnet-list-object-cannot-be-coerced-to-type-double)

Comment: Is `x` a matrix or a dataframe?